# React components not updating automatically in production build

Tags: reactjs, heroku, production

I'm developing a component which uses react-swipeable. When the user swipes left or right, the card value changes.

```
const values = [
'1',
'2',
'3',
'5',
'8',
'13',
'20',
'40'
]

export default class UserContainer extends React.PureComponent{
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        currentIndex: 0,
        cardValue:values[0]
    }
    this.swipedRight = this.swipedRight.bind(this);    
}

swipedRight(){        
    var newIndex = this.state.currentIndex;
    if(newIndex !== 0){
        newIndex-=1;
        this.setState({
            currentIndex : newIndex,
            cardValue: values[newIndex]
        });
    }  
}

render(){    
    return(  
        <Grid>
            <Row is="center">
                <div style={{width:'170px'}} className={this.state.animationClass}>
                    <Swipeable onSwipedUp={this.swipedUp} onSwipedRight={this.swipedRight} onSwipedLeft={this.swipedLeft} >                  
                        <User cardValue={this.state.cardValue} userName={this.props.params.userName} />                                                                        
                    </Swipeable>   
                </div>   
            </Row>
        </Grid>                                                                                
    );
}
}
```

When I run npm-start (I'm using create-react-app), it works fine. I deployed it using heroku, first running npm run build, then pushing to heroku master.

When I try to use my app in production, the route is working, but when I swipe (using chrome toggle device toolbar) it does not update automatically. If I press F12, then it updates. I'd like to know what is wrong.

My app link is: https://poc-planning-poker.herokuapp.com/

1) Open two tabs using the link above
2) On Tab#1, click New Room, then copy the roomId
3) On Tab#2, fill nickname, paste the roomId in code field, then click Join Room

The Tab#1 should update automatically with the user who just joined (It's working in dev env). It only updates if I press F12, which is weird.

Any ideas please?

Edit: the source code is here: https://github.com/danruziska/poc-planning-poker

Edit2: I also realized that when I use setState in an array, it calls render, but the UI is not automatically updated. If I setState a single value, it works...

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem (kind of). There was a conflict with another component that i used: react-inline-grid. When I took of the Grid, it worked again.